# FluentNHibernate Bug with ColumnName?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

if my ClassMap contains a **Reference(m => m.Store).Column("StoreId")** and I call SchemaExport, then my database table contains two foreign key columns, one named 'StoreId' and one named 'Store_id'.

If I leave the Column() method, then its only gonna create the 'Store_id' column.

Is this a bug in the FluentNHibernate framework?
I'd like to have the 'StoreId' column only.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class EntityMap<T> : ClassMap<T> where T : Entity
{
    public EntityMap()
    {
        Id( m => m.Id );
    }
}

public class StoreMap : EntityMap<Store>
{
    public StoreMap()
    {
        Map( m => m.Name );
        HasMany( m => m.Staff )
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
        HasManyToMany( m => m.Catalogue )
            .Table( "Store_Product" )
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class EmployeeMap : EntityMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        Map( m => m.LastName );
        Map( m => m.FirstName );
        References( m => m.Store ).Column( "StoreId" );
    }
}

public class ProductMap : EntityMap<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        Map( m => m.Name );
        HasManyToMany( m => m.Stores )
            .Table( "Store_Product" )
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post your mappings for the Store and the other class (the one that is referencing Store).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated my post with the mapping classes.

Comment: Do you have any other links to your store class that you are not posting here?  Also try changing your store map to Id(m => m.Id).Column("StoreId")

Comment: I've updated my first post. Now its the whole ClassMap. I'd like to keep my entity Id's named 'Id'.

Comment: Try using ParentKeyColumn and ChildKeyColumn on your HasManyToMany's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution now, though its not described anywhere I looked.

You have to set the column bidirectional. Then the "Store_id" column disappears. Thank you all for your answers!

For my above example:

```
public class EntityMap<T> : ClassMap<T> where T : Entity
{
    public EntityMap()
    {
        Id( m => m.Id );
    }
}

public class StoreMap : EntityMap<Store>
{
    public StoreMap()
    {
        Map( m => m.Name );
        HasMany( m => m.Staff )
            .KeyColumn( "StoreId" )
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
        HasManyToMany( m => m.Catalogue )
            .Table( "Store_Product" )
            .ParentKeyColumn( "StoreId" )
            .ChildKeyColumn( "ProductId" )
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class EmployeeMap : EntityMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        Map( m => m.LastName );
        Map( m => m.FirstName );
        References( m => m.Store ).Column( "StoreId" );
    }
}

public class ProductMap : EntityMap<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        Map( m => m.Name );
        HasManyToMany( m => m.Stores )
            .Table( "Store_Product" )
            .ParentKeyColumn( "ProductId" )
            .ChildKeyColumn( "StoreId" )
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, if leave column() nhibernate by default consider your foreign key is Property Name+underscore+id, you are leave column the nhhibernate take property name you are mapped called Store and merge to _id

you must add .KeyColumn("StoreId") in StoreMap for HasMany
the map look like this

```
public StoreMap()
{
    Map( m => m.Name );
    HasMany( m => m.Staff )
        .Inverse()
        .Cascade.All().KeyColumn("StoreId");
    HasManyToMany( m => m.Catalogue )
        .Table( "Store_Product" )
        .Cascade.All();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So you say it is not possible to name the foreign key column like I want ("StoreId" instead of "Store_id") ?

Comment: in your map you must remove inverse() to work correctly because inverse make your map generate foreign key twice

Comment: I don't think so. Inverse() only tells the Employee to do the storing and shouldn't has anything to do with the FK. Though, I removed it experimentally, but its still 'Store_id'.

Comment: I updated my answer you must add .KeyColumn("StoreId") in store map

Comment: Tried that, still get two FK columns, where only the 'Store_id' column will be set, the 'StoreId' is always NULL.

Comment: I'm sure this code work correctly. wich version of fluent nhibernate use? I use fluent nhibernate version 1.3.0.717 with nhibernate 3.2

Comment: Ok, I think this is a bug. I've downloaded the src and started the Examples.FirstProject. Then the ONLY thing I changed: I added ".Column( "StoreId" )" behind "References( x => x.Store )" in this Example. Then I browsed the SQLite DB and now there are also two columns in the Employee table: "StoreId" and "Store_id". FluentNHibernate version 1.2.132. Where to get this newer version?